# How to get notification when a new text is added to a file?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, push-notification, notifications

There is a text file that errors from a script will be saved into.

Each error on a new line, Then these errors will be shown on a new admin menu.

Here is the code to save the errors:

```
$error = 'Error Message';
file_put_contents('erros.txt', $error.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Getting the errors from that text file:

```
file_get_contents('errors.txt');
```

My question is how to create a notification when a new error is thrown to that file?

Something like when a new WordPress update, Or stackoverflow notifications.

Should I for example add some code beneath the `file_put_contants()` function that creates the notification?

It doesn't be so fancy, Maybe just a red element without numbers, Something that tells there is a new text added.

[image: WordPress Notifications Screenshot]

Comment: Not sure if i understand the question. Do you want to make an alert to the user that there was an error?

Comment: @JoppeDeCuyper, Yes when an error happens a message will be saved to the text file, When a new message is added to that file, A notification appears there

Comment: Or any other way to notify the admin that an error happens in the script running by the cron job

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: I tried another idea, But if you have an idea or a solution I would like to know

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes into my mind: use an alias for file_put_contents and whenever you add text to the file you insert a value in a DB. At this point it is "easy" to know how many unread notifications you have.

Comment: I mean I could do that and save a value in the DB and show it, But how to know that the admin saw the new massages to reset that value to 0 for example?

Answer (score 0):

you could use filemtime to see if the file got modified since last check

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php